# How to search a cell in Google Sheets that has multiple words for a specific word and return a result?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. A project manager fills out a Google Form. It spits the result to a spreadsheet, and I want to manipulate that data.
2. The first question/cell is what social media the product is using, with a multiple choice checkbox.
3. If someone checks off Facebook and Twitter, the cell returns "Facebook, Twitter" and I'm having trouble searching the cell for "Twitter" since it's not first.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function testplan() {

var mainsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var testplan = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TestPlan");

var socialData = mainsheet.getRange(3, 3).getValues();
var socialDataText = socialData.length;
var fbSocial = "Facebook";
var twitSocial = "Twitter";

for (var i = 0; i < socialDataText; i++) {
if (socialData[i][0] == fbSocial) {
  testplan.getRange("A15").setValue("User can log into the app with Facebook.");
  testplan.getRange("A16").setValue("User can share content from the app with Facebook.");
} {
  return 0;
};
};

for (var i = 0; i < socialDataText; i++) {
if (socialData[i][0] == twitSocial) {;
  testplan.getRange("A17").setValue("User can log into the app with Twitter.");
  testplan.getRange("A18").setValue("User can share content from the app with Twitter.");
                     } {
     return 0;
};
};
```

The first command to look for "Facebook" works, because it's the first bit of text. But anything after it isn't able to be found. I've searched a lot and have found things that are close, but nothing that works the way I'm expecting it to. It's probably a command or something really obvious that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
function testplan() {

    var mainsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var testplan = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TestPlan");

    var socialData = mainsheet.getRange(3, 3).getValues();
    var socialDataText = socialData.length;
    var fbSocial = "Facebook";
    var twitSocial = "Twitter";

    for (var i = 0; i < socialDataText; i++) {
        if (socialData[i][0].indexOf(fbSocial) > -1) {
          testplan.getRange("A15").setValue("User can log into the app with Facebook.");
          testplan.getRange("A16").setValue("User can share content from the app with Facebook.");
        };
        if (socialData[i][0].indexOf(twitSocial) > -1) {;
          testplan.getRange("A17").setValue("User can log into the app with Twitter.");
          testplan.getRange("A18").setValue("User can share content from the app with Twitter.");            
        };
    };
};
```

for simplicity

Comment: @SpencerEaston you don't need to split it into an array. the indexOf will look for 'Facebook' and 'Twitter' from a string

Comment: Yeah this worked, also if I could point to the right cell lol